# Change .htaccess to work ?_escaped_fragment_= URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an AJAX web app I need google to index. So I've used hashbang and I need to pass the  ?_escaped_fragment_= to a separate crawler PHP.

Currently

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^$ crawler.php?cat=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Redirects to url like this /crawler.php/m/GkQs6Mw4W8. How can I redirect the crawler to a URL like this,

```
crawler.php?cat=m&id=GkQs6Mw4W8
```

how should I change the .htaccess file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add new rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^$ crawler.php?cat=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^crawler\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ crawler.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: @anubuwa I'm afraid echo $_REQUEST['cat']; still returns /m/GkQs6Mw4W8

Comment: Do you have other rules also? There is no way `([^/]+)` can match ` /m/GkQs6Mw4W8`

Comment: yah what if there are other options like /e/GkQs6Mw4W8, or like /about etc? how can we do that if there are single parameters too